# Should I always stop clocks that I start for react-native-reanimated?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have created a Progress component that shows infinite animation, so I have a runTiming() function similar as [in example](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/blob/1.9.0/Example/src/src/interpolate/Basic.js).

However the example does not stop the clock, so I wonder if this is good practice? My intuition says that I should stop the clock in componentWillUnmount, however I was not able to find a way to do it.